# Best way to declare specific width variables depending on user input

Tags: c, reusability, stdint

I have a code which looks as shown below. The code here is if the `word_size = 64`. In similar fashion I need to have for 32 and 16 too. I can't find a way to reuse the same `encrypt` function for all the sizes. Moreover, I need to declare the variables too according to the word_size, ie. to use either `uint_16` or `uint_32` or `uint_64` depends upon word_size. Can you help me with writing a reusable code in this case?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

void encrypt(uint64_t* , uint64_t*, uint64_t*);

int main(){

    int block_size;

    // Get the user inputs
    printf("input the block size: \n");
    scanf("%d", &block_size);   // can be 32, 64 or 128

    int word_size = block_size/2;   // 16,32 or 64

    // Depending on the word_size, I should declare the variables with 
    // corresponding width
    uint64_t plain_text[2] = {0,0};  
    uint64_t cipher_text[2] = {0,0}; 
    uint64_t key_text[2] = {0,0};   

    uint64_t * pt, *ct, *k;
    encrypt(pt, ct,k);
    }

 /*
 * Ecnryption Method
 */
void encrypt(uint64_t* pt, uint64_t* ct, uint64_t* k){

    // Involves bit shifting algorithm which works only on exact sizes i.e eiter 16,32 or 64.
        }
```

I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: Define the function with the largest size, and make it accept additional width parameter. Then determine the width in the runtime, by comparing the input to the maximum values of each type.

Comment: Do you have the option of using C++? If you do, then a function template will solve your design issue.

Comment: Sorry no C++ option. isnt there an easy way in C itslef?

Comment: @EugeneSh. By doing what you said, if I pass a value of smaller size, then it gets padded with 0's on the MSB to make it 64bit, right? If thats the case, the function fails executing the algorithm.

Comment: So this is why to pass the width parameter. Your algorithm should look at it and adapt itself.

Comment: "Can you help me with writing a reusable code in this case?" - nope, but the setup is straight forward: `encrypt(void *pt, void *ct, void *k, size_t width)`. This isn't C++. There is no type-deduction that will save you so you have to provide your own via parametrization. If you're expecting to send *only* three naked pointers to a function and have it magically deduce the size of the data at the addresses contained therein it isn't going to happen. That isn't how the language works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in C - by using `struct` and `union`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

enum type {
    U64,
    U32,
    U16,
    U8,
};
struct container {
    enum type type;
    union {
        uint64_t u64;
        uint32_t u32;
        uint16_t u16;
        uint8_t  u8;
    } value;
};

int test(struct container container) {
    switch(container.type) {
        case U64:
            printf("Value is  :%" PRIu64 "\n", container.value);
            break;
        case U32:
            printf("Value is  :%" PRIu32 "\n", container.value);
            break;
        case U16:
            printf("Value is  :%" PRIu16 "\n", container.value);
            break;
        case U8:
            printf("Value is  :%" PRIu8 "\n", container.value);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct container c1, c2;

    c1.type = U64;
    c1.value.u64 = 10000000000ULL;

    c2.type = U8;
    c2.value.u8 = 100;

    test(c1);
    test(c2);
    return 0;
}
```

The output produced was:

```
Value is  :10000000000
Value is  :100
```

Comment: Let me know if you would like me to try and give you an example with your code instead of the sample code I've used.

Comment: You might need to define different bit masks too?